# OnPressed Parameter issue with Text

Tags: flutter

```
   Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                        );
                      }
                  ),
                ),
```

Hi, could someone take a look at this code? I am having issues implementing switching pages in Flutter. The parameter for onPressed is not defined. This would mean that I need to put the function on a button or not? Can't I have the function be on the container along with the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the property `onPressed` inside the widget `Text`. The class `Text` does not have an `onPressed` property, you can check here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

If you want to use the `onPressed` property then you can use the widget `RaisedButton` for example.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

We don't apply onPressed on Text. 
It is available for Buttons such as Raised buttons.

Refer : [Raised button](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Text` widget in a `GestureDetector` widget like this:

```
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 39, 79, 1),
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Text(
        "Login",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```